# Send email to distribution list SharePoint 2010 designer

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

Created an email workflow using SharePoint 2010 designer .But the email is not getting triggered for the distribution list email.

How can we send an email to distribution list using SharePoint designer.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer 2010 has reached its Support End Date, so I won’t be able to test for you. You can check out the following posts for troubleshooting suggestions:

1. Check if you have created the DL group with proper settings:

   [Create an E-mail Distribution Group – SharePoint 2010.](http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2013/03/create-e-mail-distribution-group.html)
2. Check your Exchange server settings:

   [Send an email to distribution group using SPD Workflow.](http://naga1208.blogspot.com/2015/12/send-email-to-distribution-group-using.html) /
   [Can a workflow send email to distrubtion list?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b3babd36-a8f3-45a5-8332-e3c9136c4f24/can-a-workflow-send-email-to-distrubtion-list)

Comment: Can you please let me know if we can send emails to distribution list using SharePoint designer 2013

Comment: @Priyanka It’s not that different from using SharePoint Designer 2010, you will need to build a SharePoint 2010 workflow to do that since 2013 workflow has removed this function. Make sure your group has a valid email address, and also set the `Accept messages from authenticated users only` setting of the group to `No` to see the result.

Comment: @Priyanka :  a note about Chelsea_MSFT’s answer:  should you ever migrate to SharePoint Online, if you use a SharePoint 2010-type workflow, it will not execute and will not be editable.  You will need to refactor the workflow into a 2013 workflow *or* to Microsoft Flow.  See here:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sharepoint-2010-workflow-retirement-1ca3fff8-9985-410a-85aa-8120f626965f